# Applying substr on a string

Tags: r, substring, substitution

I want to exchange one position in a characterstring with multiple characters in a loop/apply.

I have the string: "UGCACGU" and 
I want: c("AGCACGU", "CGCACGU", "GGCACGU")

What I tried was the following, but it does not work.

```
y <- c("A", "C", "G")
sapply(y, function(i) substr("UGCACGU", start = 1, stop = 1) <- i)

Error in substr("UGCACGU", start = 1, stop = 1) <- i : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

After some research I came across a idea using assign, but this does not work for me.

```
sapply(y, function(i) assign(substr("UGCACGU", start = 1, stop = 1), i))
```

Any ideas? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `sub` to replace the first letter, i.e.

```
sapply(y, function(i) sub('^[A-Z]', i, "UGCACGU"))

#        A         C         G 
#"AGCACGU" "CGCACGU" "GGCACGU"
```

Comment: Or explicitly at the beginning with an anchor, like `'^[A-Z]'` or `'^.'` if you are feeling lazy and adventurous. Also, `{1}` is not necessary.

Comment: @lmo thanks for the suggestions. I am very very new to regex so staff like anchors and lookarounds are still not clear in my head. I need to practice more

Answer (score 4):

We can use `paste` with `substring`

```
paste0(y, substring(str1, 2))
#[1] "AGCACGU" "CGCACGU" "GGCACGU"
```